# How to create multiple instances of same field type in django?

Tags: django, forms, dynamic, models, multiple-instances

lets say i have model classroom:

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    number_of_students = models.IntegerField()
```

and each classroom can have different number of students. I would like to have class students which is related to classroom model

```
class Students(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    student_gender = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom)
```

I want when i enter the number of students to get new form for each student. How could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Make `number_of_students` a property of the classroom that just does a simple query to retrieve it, theres no need to store an arbitrary number

```
@property
def number_of_students(self):
    return self.students_set.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing what you're looking for is dynamic form generation. A couple of pointers :

1) The best way (IMO) to do this would be to use some javascript library to append forms on the fly. Keep checking for user input and add/remove forms on the fly. You can use ids such as `form_1`, `form_2` to distinguish the student forms.

2) Then, on your backend you would loop over the `POST` params and manually create the student fields (After having created your class). How will you know how many students the user filled in (i.e. how many student forms have been submitted)? Pass the user input as a hidden field in your form and subsequently loop over it.

This would enable you to give a single view for creating the class and its students.

The other option :

1) Pass the number of students to your `StudentCreationForm` (or `ClassCreationForm`) as an extra argument during `init`. This requires you to take the number of students as input from your user on a previous page (via ajax/post). The below link provides an excellent tutorial on how to achieve this:

https://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/